# how can i transfer money from another bank account into my credit card?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, check

Hello Please how can i transfer money from another bank account into my credit card

Comment: You mean make a payment? Why can't you send a check? Why have you tagged the question as "IRA" and STOCKS"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the credit card web site, add the bank account as a payment method.

Answer (score 1):

You send a check for the account to the credit card company, with your credit card number on it. They attach little slips for that to the bill.

Most banks allow to trigger this online, no matter where the credit card is from; this is faster and easier.

Comment: Would have been a good answer a couple of decades ago.  Today?  Not that many people still do paper bills and snail mail.